# How to regex match a hyphenated company name without whitespace preceding the hyphen?

Tags: regex

My c#.net application has a boolean logic-enabled company name search field.  As such it should allow users to search for either "Hewlett-Packard" to find that company or "Foo -tankers" where the resultset is all companies with the word "Foo" but without the word "tankers" in it.

What regex expression should I use to distinguish those company searches that have no whitespace before the hyphen from those which have one or more whitespaces before the hyphen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the user can enter any number of terms in the search field, in an arbitrary order.    If so, performing a regex on the whole string is probably not the best way to go.

A better method is to [split the search text into individual terms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), using whitespace as the delimiter.

Once you do this, it is a simple matter to see which terms start with a dash.

Comment: I had marked acheong87's as the accepted answer until seeing Dan1111's post.  Dan is correct: A SPLIT function is the way to go.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a (negative) lookbehind assertion. This matches a hyphen *not* following a whitespace character:

```
(?<!\s)-
```

This matches a hyphen that *does* follow a whitespace character:

```
(?<=\s)-
```

Overall though, I'd use these two expressions to find company names and exclusions, respectively:

```
\w[\w-]*

-\w[\w-]*
```